# check_box acceptance is not working in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm new with Ruby, and I'm trying to add a simple checkbox in the redmine registration page to add a TOS and to store for every user the acceptation of the TOS.

I made the migration script:

```
class AddTosCheckbox < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :tos_accepted, :boolean, :default => false, :null => false
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :tos_accepted
  end
end
```

After rake with that, the user model was modified adding the tos_accepted field:

```
  safe_attributes 'login',
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'mail',
    'mail_notification',
    'language',
    'custom_field_values',
    'custom_fields',
    'identity_url',
    'tos_accepted'
```

And finally, at the users registration form, I added the following field:

```
<p><%= f.check_box :tos_accepted, :acceptance => true %></p>
```

But my problem is: Acceptance => true is not working; and the user can do the registration without accept the TOS.

What's the right syntax to check the acceptance of the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acceptance goes in the model, not the view

```
Class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :tos_accepted, acceptance: true
end
```

Oh and it's a virtual attribute, it doesn't need a db column.

Comment: Thank you, the fact that 'required' goes in the view made me get wrong.

Comment: Only one more thing, to use it correctly, I needed to use  "validates :tos_accepted, acceptance: { accept: true }" instead of your solution, because I'm storing the value in DB. But you show me the right path!

Answer (score 1):

In UsersController

```
def new
 @user = User.new({tos_accepted: true})
 # YOUR CODE GOES HERE
end
```

In new.html.erb

```
<%= f.check_box :tos_accepted %>
```

It will render the checkbox as checked. And then you need to add the model level of validation as Baloo suggested.

Comment: Thank you too. I'm not interested in the checkbox marked by default, but it's interesting learn how to do it for the future.